# Using the query module to get an image path. How do I get to the thumb folder?

Tags: zoo-visitor, query-module

First of all. Big thank you to [Rob Sanchez](https://twitter.com/_rsan). I'm using [his plugin](https://github.com/rsanchez/parse_file_paths) inside the  query module to get a zoo-visitor member-picture and add it to a public profile page.

This is the query. field_id_37 contains something like {filedir_1}filename.jpg.

```
{exp:query limit="1" sql="
SELECT ct.author_id, ct.entry_id, ct.channel_id, cd.field_id_37
FROM exp_channel_titles ct
INNER JOIN exp_channel_data cd
USING(entry_id)
WHERE author_id = '{embed:lid}' AND ct.channel_id = '6' 
"}

{exp:parse_file_paths}
{field_id_37}
{/exp:parse_file_paths}

{/exp:query}
```

This works fine. The output is something like: http://mysite.com/picture/filename.jpg

I do need this information to create a link to the full picture. I'd like to show the thumb as well. And that is what this question is about. How do i change the path from
http://mysite.com/picture/filename.jpg to http://mysite.com/picture/_thumb/filename.jpg?

If I didn't use the Query module, but simply the channel:entries tag the solution would be simple:

```
{field_id_37:thumb}
```

How can i rewrite the default path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using the SQL REPLACE functionality:

```
{exp:query limit="1" sql="
SELECT ct.author_id, ct.entry_id, ct.channel_id,
REPLACE (cd.field_id_37, '\{filedir_1\}', '') AS myfile
FROM exp_channel_titles ct
INNER JOIN
exp_channel_data cd
USING(entry_id)
WHERE author_id = '{embed:lid}' AND ct.channel_id = '6' 
"}

{if myfile == ""}
    {site_url}/pic/nofile.gif
{if:else}
    {site_url}/picture/_thumb/{myfile}
{/if}

{/exp:query}
```

So, for future reference and for those interested. If you only want the full filename, without a path and you're using the query module... Use the REPLACE functionality.

If there is a better way to solve this, i'd love to hear it. I'll be keeping an eye out for other solutions.